# SPFx Fast serve error on adding new class

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have started using SPFx Fast Serve to enable serving the changes fast in my SPFx web part. However it is throwing error when I add new class to scss file and use that in my react component.

The error message:

> Property 'class name' does not exists on type

[image]

If I stop the npm run serve and then runs it again, then it works fine. But it is slowing my development experience for every class that I add.

When I installed this yesterday it was working fine with addition of new class but today it is giving me this. I haven't done any changes to dev. environment since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Me and my team mates still get this error randomly but I found workaround for this issue.

If I save en-us.js file without making any modification, the error doesn't occur on subsequent addition of new classes. This saves time compared to stopping and starting npm run serve command again.